# How to make a class in one file work with UIWebViewController implemented in another file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

So I have a UIWebView implemented in one .m file and a UITableView implemented in another. When a user clicks UITableView element, the UIWebView appears. The problem is that I have to set UIWebView's content (local text and images) depending on the UITableView's row number. I know how to do this, but this, of course must be implemented with the UITableView but it also needs UIWebView.

Just importing the UIWebView implementation does'n work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have the url to be displayed in the webview  in the tableview?

Comment: No. When user taps the UITableView row, the UIWebView appears as a next view in the Nav Controller. The UIWebView contains text with images (the contents depend on the UITableView row selected).

Comment: Have you tried passing the information you need (row number, image locations, etc) to the `UIWebView` before you push it onto the Navigation Controller?

Comment: Use delegate methods to get the data from the table view to the webview

Comment: Even if I do it like this, I'll have to access the UIWebView from my UITableView implementation file, won't I?

Comment: @Warrior
How can I do this? 

Sorry, I'm a newbie

Comment: in didSelectRowAtIndexPath set the delegate and push to the corresponding webview.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. I'm not quite familiar with delegates. Which delegate should I set and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this link to for setting delegates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238103/objective-c-how-can-i-access-string-variable-as-a-global/2325857#2325857)

In  didSelectRowAtIndexpath

```
 NSString *name=@"content of table";
 myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate setCurrentTitle:name]; 

PictureWebViewController *webview = [[PictureWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PictureWebViewController" bundle:nil];


[self.navigationController pushViewController:email animated:YES];
```

the PictureWebViewController is class of your webview .

In that class in viewdidload method get the title as

```
  myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  NSString *name= [appDelegate getCurrentTitle];
```

Use the name in this class to display the content in webview.

All the Best