# Global variables?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How do I use global variables in x-code(iphone). For example, lets say i want to declare a bunch of variables(NSStrings) in the viewcontroller file, then how would i access them throughout my different classes? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are global variables.  You use them the same way you would in any C program, which is to say typically they'd be declared in something like "globals.h" and imported wherever needed.

With that said, it's generally poor practice to rely on globals.  You might have an "ApplicationController" object which in essence tracks the global state of the application, but its variables should be instance variables and either accessed only internally, or via getters/setters.

If you wanted to declare a bunch of strings in a single object to be referenced by many other objects, typically you'd make that object a Singleton and pass a reference to it to each object needing access to it.

However, you need to ask yourself *WHY* you need to do that and if there isn't a better way.  I'll bet dollars to doughnuts there's not a good reason for what you're trying to do.

Give us some more details on what the overriding need is for these strings to be global, and then we can show you reasons why they don't. :)

Comment: upvote. This is how you'd declare a global variable, but it's very likely that theres a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: In each of my classes(20) I have an action that requires the use of (for example) 20 strings. Each class uses the same strings, and rather than declare them in each and every class, i was wondering if there was a way to just declare them once, and then use them in all my classes.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [singleton](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=iphone+singleton+site%3Astackoverflow.com&) if it's not too over-killed. Another option is [NSDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nsdefaults+global+iphone). Of course, the simplest way is simply define an extern in .h

```
  extern NSString * const STR_1;
```

and the value in .m:

```
  NSString * const STR_1 = @"String One";
```

Answer (score 0):

just declare your variables in the .h file and then import this file in any class you want to use it. You can make any type of object or variable global.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the variable in delegates, You can access those variable in any other controllers using setter and getter methods to access.

See [Warrior Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238103/objective-c-how-can-i-access-string-variable-as-a-global/2325857#2325857)

I hope,it will help you.